# Line segments using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file like in four columns representing x1, y1, x2, y2.

e.g

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
```

etc.

Now I want to plot line segments using (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) as end points of the line segments. Thus I shall get 4 line segments from the above data file.

How can I achieve this using gnuplot ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this easily.

```
1 2
3 4

2 3
4 5
...
```

does this. You just need to add an extra line between each set of cordinates.

Hope this hepls.

Comment: @FlorianPrud'homme no idea

Comment: perhaps, the guy wanted a plot command like : "plot 'filename' with linespoints ls 1"

Answer (score 12):

You can simply do

```
dataf = 'yourfilename.dat'
plot dataf using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors nohead
```

without changing your original data file.